# Calculated Column that counts from 1-53 per week from specific start date

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I am facing a relatively trivial problem. I have a list of start dates for each fiscal year. For example, 03.01.2019 for the 2019 financial year or 30.12.2019 for the 2020 financial year.
Now I want the calculated column in my calendar table (Power Pivot) to count up from the start date from 1-53 per week until the next start date.

It would look like this:

- 03.01.2019 - 1
- 04.01.2019 - 1 ....

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Where are your start dates stored? What are possible start dates values? Can you please post a better example with a few cases beacuse at the moment it looks like if a simple calculated column `=Date.WeekOfYear([YourDate])` would do it.

Comment: The start dates could be stored within the function itself - I would propose. The function should be a dax function. Your approach would not work.

Comment: You didnt get what I asked for. I was basically asking if your static dates could be also a different then the start or the end of the year. Because if you just have the start and the end of the year as your fixed dates you can use (this time in DAX: `=WEEKNUM([YourDate], 2)`)

Comment: Ok, now I have you. Sorry! But then I get for the start date "30.12.2019" week number "53" instead of "1". How would you avoid that?

Comment: How about `= IF ( WEEKNUM ( [YourDate], 2) = 53, 1, WEEKNUM ( [YourDate], 2))`

Answer (score 1):

You cen get the ISO 8601 weeknumbers by adding `21` in the optional part. Here a quick example I created. But if you also have dates which start in the middle of the year you should go with a calendar, like @Kosuke Sakai posted:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the recommended approach for this requirement is to prepare a fiscal calendar in the data source (DWH, MDM, Excel, or somewhere), rather than to calculate with DAX.

Having said that, it is possible with DAX.

Assuming you have a table like below. (Let's call it FiscalYears)

[image: FiscalYear]

First, you need to add FiscalYear calculated column to your Calendar table with following formula.

```
FiscalYear :=
VAR CurrentDate = [Date]
RETURN CALCULATE (
    MAX ( FiscalYears[FiscalYear] ),
    FiscalYears[StartDate] <= CurrentDate
)
```

Then, you can use this to calculate WeekNumberInFiscalYear column.

```
WeekNumberInFiscalYear :=
VAR StartDate = LOOKUPVALUE (
    FiscalYears[StartDate],
    FiscalYears[FiscalYear],
    [FiscalYear]
)
RETURN DATEDIFF ( StartDate, [Date], WEEK ) + 1
```

The result will be looking like below.

[image: Result 1]
[image: Result 2]